# Where do i add my dependencies? In which build.gradle to put them?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, dependencies

I am requested to add a few dependencies. I know They should be added on build.gradle, but in the dependencies  section is written:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

I am new to android so from my small experience and googling there are supposed to be two build.gradle files, and only in one of them I should add dependencies, but I can not find an extra build.gradle file!?

I will be happy for help! Where should I add my dependencies and where did my second build.gradle disappear?

Comment: Show the rest of your build.gradle? There should be a second dependencies section in a `allprojects` or `subprojects` section. Add them there.

Comment: You have to add depedencies in the build.gradle inside the module not in the file in the root folder.

Comment: first of all thanks for the fast comments!


RaGe this is all the content.

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

Comment: and Gabriele I don't really understand the formal expressions of module and root folder... please elaborate, what is the module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle is a bit of an odd tool. 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

They state here how it works. There is only one build.gradle per project that will pull and manage dependencies for you.

Android Studio extends this. There is one 'main' build.gradle for the entire project, and then for each submodule there is a build.gradle since they are run as separate programs. in the master project build.gradle, put dependencies that effect everything you are doing in the build process, and then for each module dependencies specific for those modules. That's what it's saying.

[image: App (submodule) and project gradle]

http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

**EDIT: **

Android Studio docs:

> Declare dependencies
>
> The app module in this example declares three dependencies:
>
> ```
> dependencies {
> // Module dependency
> compile project(":lib")
>
> // Remote binary dependency
> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
>
> // Local binary dependency
> compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) }
> ```
>
> Each of these dependencies is described below. The build system adds all the compile
>   dependencies to the compilation classpath and includes them in the
>   final package.

Gradle docs:

> Example 7.1. Declaring dependencies
>
> build.gradle
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'java'
>
> repositories {
>     mavenCentral()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
>     testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
> }
> ```

Dependencies can be listed in a bunch of different ways.

Comment: thanks,
I actually tried to up vote your answer but I still don't have enough reputation.

I understood from you the reason why there is only one build.gradle, do you might know also where to add the dependencies!

thanks again for the explenation!

Comment: @Tomer No problem! Gradle is a general scripting language as well, based off of groovy. You can list any repo or dependency in the dependency code block as you like, and gradle build will automatically pull them for your project. It's all in the two links I sent.

Comment: *but more times than not a program like maven gits called to pull and manage those dependencies.* This is incorrect. Gradle has its own dependency resolving and caching mechanism, which is infact superior to Maven's. It can use maven repos - which does not mean it is using maven underneath. If anything gradle is close to ivy than maven.

Comment: @RaGe You are correct, I have touched gradle in a long while, and using maven underneath was then. Fixed.